# glewIsSupported(GL_VERSION_3_1) return true when the machine does not support opengl 3.1

Tags: opengl, glew

I am using `glewIsSupported(GL_VERSION_3_1)` to see if the machine supports the opengl version 3.1. It return true but I know machine only supports upto 2.1 as I checked it through `glxinfo`. I want to check for 3.1 forward compatibility profile not backward compatibility.

1. Is there a way I can tell glewIsSupported to check for forward compatibility profile or Core profile if checked for version >=3.2
2. I also tried for opengl 3.2 and opengl 3.3 support. It return true for opengl 3.2 but fails for opengl 3.3. So if it checks for compatible profile, should not it pass for both or fail for both.

I think this should be simple enough if `glxinfo` is saying it supports only upto 2.1, `glewIsSupported(GL_VERSION_3_1)` should return false. Why does it return true?

Comment: Well, `glewIsSupported` doesn't care about profiles and forward/backward compatibility. What it actually tells you is that the GL features which were added in GL 3.1 are available, which is still true for a GL3.2 coroe profile context.

Comment: but it fails for 3.3. Also glxinfo shows only 2.1 support. Don't you think there must be something wrong?

Comment: glxinfo (at least in recent versions) will report both a legacy GL version as well as a core profile version. It is totally unclear to me what your implementation actually supports.

Comment: For GL 3.1, you can test the compatibility extension. Generally, you cannot know what's supported until you create a context though. That's why there's a window manager extension to let you request a specific version. It's almost worth pretending 3.1 never existed for all the complexities it causes.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can tell glewIsSupported to check for forward compatibility profile or Core profile if checked for version >=3.2

GLEW is modified-BSD-licensed. So just change the code. Or even better, write your own function that does the same job.

In any case, no, there is no GLEW option for that.

> I want to use one code for both wondows and linux.

You can't.

Context creation is a part of the operating system *around* OpenGL. As such, it cannot be cross-platform. So either you're going to have to use someone else's context creation system or you're going

FYI: X Windows has the GLX_ARB_create_context. Obviously it won't be available on Windows, but that's how you would test that on Linux.

Comment: I think I was wrong about the glewIsSupported checking for compatible profile and all. I could not find any document to support that. So I think glewIsSupported(GL_VERSION_3_1) should fail as glxinfo is saying it supports only upto 2.1 version. I have updated the question also with more information. Do you have some idea why glewIsSupported is returning true?